# Loading a eclipse pluggin from jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to run a sample plugin

The extracted zip comprises of 2 jar files . So i loaded them into the eclipse by using the `New->PluginDevelopment->Plugin form existing jar files` wizard .

This loads the plugin but it does not run as expected . Comparing it with a sample Hello world plugin i realize that it does not have a Activator.java file and a SampleAction.java file within the src folder .

How do i get this plugin to work ? Surely there must be a way . [image]

Comment: been a while but cant you put the zip files on the project source path?

Comment: In fact,SampleAction is not necessary.

Comment: @SamSu Hmm interesting . I cant find a way that would tell the plugin to run . If i make a new plugin then automatically some deployment files are added but this zip files does not seem to have so .. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example is very old and so is difficult to get going in modern eclipse. It still is a good introduction to writing debugger plugins but after you get the gist of the article, I advise looking at the current source code for any debuggers that you might be familiar with using.

You should note that there are two plugins. Keep them separate. I found it useful to extract the jar and src zip files into their respective plugin projects.

Then you have to upgrade the plugin manifest format. There should be a warning about each item that needs to changed. There might be a upgrade function in some versions of eclipse but I couldn't find in 3.7.1.

Open the manifest in the editor and select the MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml bottom tabs to see the raw manifest. The work is mostly to move the data from plugin.xml to MANIFEST.MF. You can see it in plugin.xml and the use the editor pages to add the same information. Then delete it from plugin.xml. As you point out, one of the manifest items is the activation class. In the old plugin.xml format, this in in the Plugin/@Class attribute, so move it to the Activator field.

You'll end up with a few warnings about deprecated APIs. You can leave them or rewrite the simple functions that use them.

To run the plugins you need to run an `Eclipse Application` launch (run/debug configuration).

The two plugins in the example don't create main toolbars or menus. You can see that they are loaded via `Help > About > Installation Details > Plug-ins`.  You should now be able to switch to the Debug perspective and open the Data Stack view.  And, also `Debug > Debug Configurations > Push Down Automata` will list PDA launch configurations. Note: You can set breakpoints in .pda files (Ctrl+Shift+B) but the plugins don't implement vertical editor ruler markers so you can only see them in the Breakpoints view.

Comment: thanks alot . i am going to try this out now . Btw did u get it to run on your system after making the changes that you described above ? Interstingly i thought that this was a single plugin . If they are 2 seperate ones then how will they core part communicate with the UI part . Sorry just a bit confused here . Also would it be a smart move to download and try this example in a 2004 eclipse (IF i find it ! ) but thanks so much to see this .

Comment: I wouldn't go earlier than eclipse 3.0. Anyway, here's a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oanoddqqdaz2fvs/Eclipse%20Debugger%20Example%20Projects%20for%20Eclipse%20SDK%203.7.1.zip) to the projects I reworked a bit. Plugins communicate through Plugin Dependencies which is a build classpath container managed by PDE via plugin manifests. See the Dependencies page of the manifest editor. It is the UI plugin that needs the Core plugin. They are very much decoupled but understandingly, the UI views and creates things in the debug model such as breakpoints.

Comment: this is most useful . I am sure i need to study on the dependency thing . However on running the pluging (Right clink on the UI plugin ) its still does not attach to the Menu bar . Did it do for you ? If yes then maybe i still did something wrong :(

Comment: If you don't have PDE installed in your eclipse see this tutorial: [Update an Eclipse Java IDE](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#eclipsepdeinstallation_update). To test the plugins, see [Start an Eclipse IDE with your plug-in](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#firstplugin_start).

Comment: I have PDE installed . Infact i did run the HelloWorld sample .. Runs perfectly but this one still does not get attached to the menu . there is no error message to be seen in the errorlog either . Hence this makes me think that its starting (Activation)class is nver getting called . SO i asked you if you were able to attach it as a plugin to the IDE toolbar/menu bar  . if yes then surely i suck and need to see more what can go wrong. :-(

Comment: I owe this to you . I couldnt have done by myself . Not in 2 days anyways . I cant thank you enough .